# Are you able to build a settlement from a separate ship?

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

Let's say that I have a boat from island A, after a few turns I move boat to island B, now can I start a settlement on island B? Or do I have to make a full shipping line from Island A to Island B or can I just move one ship to island B and start a settlement?

I have read the Seafarers rules booklet, but I have not been able to find any information on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boats are like roads with a few exceptions:

- they must border at least on one side to water.
- they require wood and sheep to build.
- you can pivot the last ship in a row of ships (but it needs to stay connected).
- they are affected by pirates

You can only change from road to ship (or ship to road) through a settlement (or city).

In order to build a settlement on an Island where you have no settlement yet, you need to build a row of ships starting from a settlement at the first island until you get to the second island. You can now continue building ships along the coast, or you can build a settlement. And if you are the first to build on an island, some scenario's reward you with an extra victorypoint.

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood the ship "movement" rules, I thought you could just move your ship around anywhere you wanted. Thanks for the clarification @Toon Krijthe

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a full shipping line. If you want to move a ship, you have to place it so that it is attached to another ship, or to a city or settlement.

You can never reach another island with just one ship.

Comment: You can reach an island with one ship, if there is only one sea tile between two islands. You can't build a settlement because of the distance rule ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The manual doesn't clearly state if a shipping route needs to be connected to a city, so

> If your shipping route reaches a coastline, you can then build a new settlement on that coast, even if it's a new island.

is everything I can find on that topic.

Source [Catan: Seafarers Manual](http://www.catan.de/files/downloads/seafarers_rv_rules_111105.pdf)